# Setting Session Variable on Popup Focus In ADF

Tags: java, oracle-adf

I have an application that is somewhat heavy on ADF Popup dialogs. They will be defined in the index page like this:

```
<af:popup id="popup1" contentDelivery="lazyUncached" binding="managedBean1">
    <jsp:include page="page1.jsp" />
</af:popup>
<af:popup id="popup2" contentDelivery="lazyUncached" binding="managedBean1">
    <jsp:include page="page2.jsp" />
</af:popup>

etc, etc.
```

What I would like to do is whenever the popup opens and/or receives the focus, I want to set a session-scoped variable named "whereami". This variable will be used for further customization of pages, context menus, etc.

Can anyone assist?

Jason

Answer (score 2):

You can attach click event to the body or div whatever, of the popup using JavaScript. And this can be achieved from backend by firing JavaScript from the Listener method of PopupFetchListener. As:

```
ExtendedRenderKitService service = Service.getRenderKitService(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), ExtendedRenderKitService.class);
service.addScript(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "yourmethod();");
```

Then you can follow either of the following way.

Add a commandButton with `actionListener` and let it hidden. From the onclick JavaScript method of the popup you can trigger the click event of that hidden button by:

```
var button = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId("hiddenButton");
ActionEvent.queue(button,true);
```

This will fire the actionListener.

Or you could take the help of `af:serverListener` to call backing method.

I didn't test it, but this should work.

Answer (score 1):

The popup component has a PopupFetchListener event. The event is fired when the popup is displayed.
Capture that method in your backing bean and set your session bean there.

Comment: I found that, but does it fire whenever the popup gets the focus, or only the first time the popup is displayed? Its possible in this app to have overlapping popups, which may screw up the whereami variable The breadcrumbs component is not an option.

Comment: Actually, I discovered the answer seems to be "no", the PopupFetchListener only fires on initial load, not popup focus.